Can't delete partitions from I/O error
I got the blue screen of death today and  the stop code was: REGISTRY_ERROR. I looked into it and couldn't fix it.
There were solutions when you are booted into Windows, which I couldn't do since it was stuck on the blue screen. I tried to fix it from command prompt but I couldn't. So I i decided to make a clean install of Windows, however I couldn't delete nor format the already existing partitions. I tried to clean the disk, delete partition override and  delete volume override with Diskpart, and always got the error the request could not be performed because of an I/O device error. I made a USB drive with Ubuntu on it, used sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt and got this which enabled me to access my files in the file explorer by searching /mnt in the search bar. I also opened GParted which showed me that there wasn't a problem with the main partition and that it was a problem with the EFI system partition and the Microsoft reserved partition (picture of GParted).
Are there any ways I can clean my disk so i can reinstall Winbdows on it from scratch since i couldn't repair it nor override it with a new installation.
EDIT: the commands i used were clean, delete partition override and delete volume override with Diskpart, and i used sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /mnt in command prompt

I/O errors almost always mean a failed drive. That's it, replace the drive, install Windows, end of story. There's nothing you can do differently in an Ubuntu live session.

This question should include more details and clarify the problem. The random bold words makes your question more difficult to understand not easier to understand. I would also agree that the disk likely is the problem. Specifics on what commands you ran are also helpful.

There are no ways to clean your disk because the disk isn't "dirty".
Your drive is most likely dead. The correct course of action is to replace it. If you do not have a backup and need to recover data, you should put your efforts into that.
